# Getting a error after calling method again(arrayList library program)

Tags: java, arraylist

```
package bookShop;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by luigi on 4/1/2016.
 */
public class Book{

    private String bTitle;
    private Double bPrice;
    private int bYear;
    private int bStock;

    private String mTitle;
    private Double mPrice;
    private int mYear;
    private int mWeek;

    private int pick;

    static ArrayList<Book> BookList = new ArrayList<Book>();

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner pickInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner pickBook = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void createBook(){
        System.out.println("Enter a Title: ");
        bTitle = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the Price: ");
        bPrice = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the publication Year: ");
        bYear = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the amount of stock: ");
        bStock = input.nextInt();
    }

    public void addBook(){
        Book newBook = new Book();
        newBook.createBook();
        BookList.add(newBook);
    }

    public void printMenu() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to your personal Book-Shop library program.");
        System.out.println("Type the number of the menu you want to use.");
        System.out.println("1: Check the books in the list.");
        System.out.println("2: Add a book to the list");
        System.out.println("3: Delete stock.");
        System.out.println("0: Exit the menu.");
        pick = pickInput.nextInt();
    }

    public void deleteStock(){
        printBookList();
        System.out.println("Type the index of the book you want to remove: ");
        int stockChoice = (pickBook.nextInt()-1);
        BookList.remove(stockChoice);

        //BookList.remove(stockChoice);
        System.out.println("You have chosen to delete the following book: "+(stockChoice+1));


    }

    public String printBook(){
        String BookInfo =   " "+
                "\n Title: "+bTitle+
                "\n Price: "+bPrice+
                "\n Year: "+bYear+
                "\n Stock: "+bStock+
                " ";
        return BookInfo;
    }

    public void printBookList(){
        for(int i=0;i<BookList.size();i++){
            System.out.printf("\n Book Number: [%s]   \n",i+1);         //***
            System.out.println(BookList.get(i).printBook());
        }
    }


    public void run(){
        printMenu();

        switch(pick){
            case 1:
                printBookList();
                run();
                break;

            case 2:
                addBook();
                run();
                break;

            case 3:
                deleteStock();
                run();
                break;


            case 0:
                System.out.println("Shutting down.");
                break;


        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book newBook = new Book();
        newBook.run();
    }


}
```

This is my code, i cannot add a title when i call addBook(); a second time after adding a first book.

Welcome to your personal Book-Shop library program.
Type the number of the menu you want to use.
1: Check the books in the list.
2: Add a book to the list
3: Delete stock.
0: Exit the menu.
1
Welcome to your personal Book-Shop library program.
Type the number of the menu you want to use.
1: Check the books in the list.
2: Add a book to the list
3: Delete stock.
0: Exit the menu.
2
Enter a Title: 
Enter the Price: 
123
Enter the publication Year: 
123
Enter the amount of stock: 
5

Comment: post your full stack trace of your exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the methods other than `printBook()` should be static as they are not associated with a particular book, the contents of `createBook()` should be in Book's constructor and `createBook()` should be deleted, run should not call itself as this will cause a `StackOverflowError` if the user provides input too many times, rather its contents should be in an infinite loop using `System.exit(0);` to shutdown the program, the new contents of `run()` should be at the end of `printMenu()` and run should be deleted, move everything in the modified `printMenu()`  into the loop, finally `printMenu()` should be called only once from `main`. Also learningphase's answer for your question my answer for your future questions on this

Comment: Thank you so much for the tips. I have another question though, im now making en extra createMagazine(); and createDVD(); with different attributes than createBook(); should i make a completely new class for Magazines and DVD's or it is easier to just keep it all in this class. Im pretty new to Java and even programming itself, once again thanks for the tips.

Comment: you could make an abstract class call it "Item" or something. Book and DVD should extend this class. if you need help with anything java email me joe.p.137.1317@gmail.com or skype me live:joe.p.137.1317 i'll be glad ho help

Answer (score 0):

Change your

bTitle = input.nextLine(); to bTitle = input.next();.

It is because nextInt for your stock method does not consume the last newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in the next call for the title. It assumes the input has already been made in form of a next line because of which it goes to the next input for price.